# Defining Global Variables or passing variables through function in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, function, global-variables, argument-passing

I have a main function and some sub-functions.
There are some indicator variables (0 or 1) that other sub-functions need them.These values are updated in functions.
Which option is better regarding to CPU speed?
1) Passing through functions
2) define global variables.

Comment: It probably depends on the number of variables you need the functions to share. Better try yourself in your specific case. Also, consider [nested functions](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/nested-functions.html): they can access and modify variables that are defined in their parent functions

Comment: I don't plan to use nested functions. There are 5 scaler global variables that other functions use and update them. the value if these variables are 0 or 1. @LuisMendo

Comment: I do not think that you will see much difference in case the variables are scalar. Especially not if you have a boolean which is one byte only. I would go for readabiltiy and maintainability, but if you are unsure you should do some benchmarking. Use `timeit` the profiler or any other suitable benchmarking tool.

Comment: While this discussion is about time let me give my opinion on style: DO NOT USE GLOBAL VARIABLES!!! I think they make code unclear, as you never know who/how are they going to be used, specially when you code grows bigger. If a function uses a variable, make it explicit that it does in the function call, if you want that variable to be optional/have a default value, then use `varargin` and `nargin`.

Comment: I take ur advice. @AnderBiguri